# How to change a sticky element's height dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs`, one is a sticky element and the other is a footer at the bottom. The site has enough height so that it's scrollable and the footer is not visible intially. What I need to achieve is, when I scroll down and the sticky element meets the footer, the height of the sticky element should be dynamically reduced in such a way that it still touches the footer but doesn't cover it up. When the sticky element's height gets too small and the content overflows, a scrollbar should appear. Is it possible to achieve this with pure CSS?

This is my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/co7dty0p/

Comment: Actually I don't understand very good what you want to achieve, you want when you scroll the header div meet the footer?

Comment: Normally the sticky element covers everything underneath it. In my case it should cover everything but only until it meets the footer. At that point when I countinue to scroll down to show the whole footer, the sticky element's height should be dynamically reduced so that it doesn't cover the footer up. So to the user the sticky element looks like it stops moving when it meets the footer, but in reality it still moves but its height is being reduced, thus it looks like it stays in place.

Comment: You have an working example from the web in action to what you want to achieve?